# Getting Mouse Position on Event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two events; mouse up and down. I get the initial position of the mouse when left button down. Then I plan to get the last position of the mouse when button released. So if there is a horizontal movement I can easily recognise. However it is problematic. Since I add listener to a movie clip, it obtain mouse x in bounds of that movie clip. What I mean is if you release button outside of the movie clip it does not work because event attached to it. Are there any turnarounds here?

```
m_c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartPoint);
m_c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, EndPoint);
```

---

```
function StartPoint(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    initX = stage.mouseX;
}
```

---

```
function EndPoint(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    lastX = stage.mouseX;
    trace("drop ", lastX);
    if(lastX < initX)
    {
        trace("goes left");
        .
        .
        .
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I think that you should attach the events listeners to your stage not your movieclip.

Comment: I agree with akmozo. Use `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, EndPoint);`

Comment: Fair enough. But I need the event like that; user clicks the movie clip, holds it, moves right or left and release (let's say mouse driven swipe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to addListener to stage, preferable in listener of MOUSE_DOWN

```
function StartPoint(event: MouseEvent) : void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, EndPoint);

    // another code
}
```